# ¿Cómo se muestra en un diagrama entidad relación que un atributo de la relación es parte de la clave de la tabla relación?

Tags: base-de-datos, relaciones, modelorelacional, atributos

Supongamos que tengo que hacer una base de datos para una librería que alquila libros. Pensé en modelar a Book y Person como una entidad y relacionarlos mediante la relación Rent. Dejo la imagen:

[image: Diagrama Entidad Relación]

Person podría tener a passport como clave y name como atributo y Book podría tener ISBN como clave y name como atributo. Si además de esto, me piden que una persona puede alquilar un mismo libro, pero en distinta fecha, me encuentro en un dilema. Si agrego date como atributo de la relación Rent, la clave de Rent solo tendría a ISBN y passport, por lo que no podría tener una upla con el mismo libro y la misma persona. Y también me parece exagerado crear una entidad llamada Date y hacer una relación ternaria. Se podría agregar a date como parte de la clave de la relación (es decir, subrayarla en el diagrama)? O no queda otra que hacer una relación ternaria?

Answer (score 2):

Una persona puede rentar N libros. Un libro puede ser rentado por M personas. Cuando normalizas eso, suele pasar que tienes una entidad intermedia donde la relación M-N se resuelve usando las claves de las dos entidades y algún otro dato propio de esa relación.

Es decir que uno podría crear una llave primaria compuesta en esa entidad intermedia (que yo llamaría Rent), y esa llave sería passport-isbn-date. Rent no sería una relación sino una entidad para resolver esa cardinalidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta! Entiendo lo que planteas y estoy completamente de acuerdo, pero cómo lo plasmaría en el diagrama? Si yo le entrego el Modelo Entidad Relación a la persona que va a generar la base de datos, cómo sabe que date tiene que ser clave?

Comment: @FrancoFerrante eso significa que tienes que hacer un modelo más detallado que este que tienes, indicando los atributos de cada entidad, su naturaleza (obligatorios o no, hacen parte de la clave o no, etc.). Revisa cómo se hace esa versión del E-R, el que tienes es el primer paso de ese proceso

Answer (score 1):

yo haría algo así, es básico pero pensando que en la librería seguramente hay más de una unidad de cada libro y que si una persona quiere alquilar al mismo tiempo todas las unidades de un libro específico.

[image: DER]

También creo que debería haber un stock, el cual se pueda descontar o sumar cuando regresan el libro. Un poco más completo sería agregar una entidad categorías para poder filtrar ya que hay muchos libros. Espero te sea útil, creo que es la forma correcta, saludos

Comment: Lo malo de poner texto como imagen es que pasan cosas como: SO tiene un tema oscuro y en ese, tu PNG con transparencia es ilegible :D O cambias la imagen a un JPG humilde con fondo blanco, o pones el texto como texto  :)